# Send Json Array Through jQuery Ajax

Tags: php, json, jquery, getjson

I am going to send a array of json object through jquery ajax call to a php file.

```
var arr = new Array();
var record1 = {'a':'1','b':'2','c':'3'};
var record2 = {'d':'4','e':'5','f':'6'};
arr.push(record1);
arr.push(record2);
```

How can I send the array through jquery ajax? and how can I get the values in php?
Thanks.

Comment: you need to serialize json object and deserialize that in you PHP code.... !!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
        url: "api",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(arr),
        success: function(response){}

       });
```

And with PHP:

```
$strRequest = file_get_contents('php://input');
$Request = json_decode($strRequest);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think `JSON.stringify()` might be useful.

or, you can use `json_decode()` in php file.

Answer (score 1):

First download and add plugin : jquery.json-2.4.js to your project.
This plugin offers a lot of helpers that will make your life easy.

Then in your $.ajax , use  data : $.toJSON(arr),

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you have to know is that you need to be with two files to make things simple for yourself .
1.  Where you going to put your php code phpcode.php
2.  Where you going to put your ajax codes  ajax.html
In the page where you going to put your ajax code make sure you connect to jquery plugins
Then

```
 <script> 
          $(document).ready(function(){
      // your ajax code here  delete mine and put your codes
    $.getJSON(' phpcode.php ', function(data) {
              $('#myJson').html('<table style="color:red"><tr><td>' + data.name + '</td><td>' + data.user + '</td></tr></table>');
            });
          });

        </script>
    <body>
    <!—You may put the bellow div in the ajax page so that u load your data in it ---->
        <div id="myJson"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
     In your php page you need something like this at the end of your code 
    // The JSON standard MIME header.
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo  json_encode($array);
    Note: I took an example from my working codes just to save the time but I think you get the Idea
```