# How post an array using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Actually I'm trying to a send `ajax` call with a data array. This is my sample code, `criteria` is an array but when I send this call it doesnt return any data. but when I tried it using php it worked perfectly. This is my sample `php` code

```
$post = array('criteria'=>array('user_id'=>'user1','subject'=>'meeting'));
$fields = (is_array($post)) ? http_build_query($post) : $post;

$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://mydomain/task/find');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);        
    $serverOutput = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    error_log('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>'.$serverOutput);
```

So what is the mistake of following code? How can I send an array using `ajax` ? please help me.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://mydomain/task/find",
    data: { "criteria" : [{'user_id':'uesr1'},{'subject':'meeting'}]},
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.status) {
            alert('ok');
        }
    },
    dataType: 'json',
});
```

actually this works for single element like this,

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://mydomain/task/find",
    data: { "criteria" : [{'user_id':user1}]},
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.status) {

        }
    },
    dataType: 'json',
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a multi-dimensional array is passed to [`http_build_query`](https://www.php.net/http_build_query) it act in a way that is unique and doesn't really exists in javascript (It is more common to use json encoded objects to send complex data)

The equivalent data object to your PHP code would be something like :

```
data: { "criteria[user_id]" : "uesr1", "criteria[subject]" : "meeting" },
```

The `php.js` library got an equivalent of the php function written in JavaScript : http://phpjs.org/functions/http_build_query/

### How is the encoding done

There is an example in the php documentation :

```
<?php
$data = array('user'=>array('name'=>'Bob Smith',
                            'age'=>47,
                            'sex'=>'M',
                            'dob'=>'5/12/1956'),
              'pastimes'=>array('golf', 'opera', 'poker', 'rap'),
              'children'=>array('bobby'=>array('age'=>12,
                                               'sex'=>'M'),
                                'sally'=>array('age'=>8,
                                               'sex'=>'F')),
              'CEO');

echo http_build_query($data, 'flags_');
?>
```

And the resulting POST data (url decoded and wrapped for better understanding) :

```
  user[name]=Bob Smith
& user[age]=47
& user[sex]=M
& user[dob]=5/12/1956
& pastimes[0]=golf
& pastimes[1]=opera
& pastimes[2]=poker
& pastimes[3]=rap
& children[bobby][age]=12
& children[bobby][sex]=M
& children[sally][age]=8
& children[sally][sex]=F
& flags_0=CEO
```

As you can see the array is flattened with brackets used to identify levels, passing the same object in jQuery as `data` would have generated something like :

```
  user={"name": "Bob Smith", "age": "47", "sex"="M", "dob": "5/12/1956"}
& passtimes=["golf", "opera", "poker", "rap"]
& children={"bobby": { "age": "12", "sex": "M"}, "sally": { "age": "8", "sex": "F"}
& flags_0="CEO"
```

If you don't know about the format used to encode POST data, see the [wikipedia article on POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) it's well writen.

Comment: wow it works !!!, but I can't understand why ? if u can please explain. thanks !!!

Comment: I added more infos with the same sample as the one in the php docs but formated for readability

Answer (score 0):

try using this syntax

```
 data:({
                criteria :[{
                    user_id: "user1",
                    subject:"meeting"
                }]
            })
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523244/send-json-array-through-jquery-ajax hope it helps